# Algorithm time complexity analysis

Tags: time, complexity-theory

I haven't got sufficient knowledge of time complexity, so my question is:

Is there any direct formula to calculate time complexity of an algorithm, example- I have read somewhere that big O of this code is n*log2(n), so can you tell me how they got this expression?

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i=i*2)
```

for this loop I am unable to calculate the big O. This loops will make 7 iterations for a value of n=100. How does that help arrive to the given formula?

Comment: example of code that is O(n^2logn)????? or else how are we to explain....

Comment: for(i=0;i<=n;i=i*2)-for this loop i am unable to calculate the big O.

Comment: This loop is infinite.

Comment: Oh sorry i made a mistake , actually its
for(i=1;i<=n;i=i*2)

Comment: Isn't it `log2(n)`?. Because binary search complexity is the same, and index every time divided by 2. And in this case multiplied by 2.

Comment: i have no freaking idea abt it, thats why m asking u , but i saw there that it shld be (n* log2(n))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**By itself, this loop will iterate through `ceil(log(n))` times**. That's `log(n)` with log base of 2. This is because  after `ceiling(log(n))` multiplications, `i` will have reached or passed `n`, for any `n`. A quick example:

For `n=100:`

```
Iteration:      i:
    1           1
    2           2
    3           4
    4           8
    5           16
    6           32
    7           64
    8           128
```

So `i` will be checked on the 8th iteration and you don't go into the loop, as it's not `<= 100`. It will be `nlog2(n)` as you suggest if there's another inner loop that fully loops through `n` times. Then the two times for the two loops get multiplied to get the total time.